# Regex extracting number with connecting dot and hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Lets say I have the following string:

```
<div style="color: red; display.: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> -18.9%</div>
```

What  want to extract is **-18.9**

I currently have [^0-9.-]+ in javascript
But that will include every dot and hyphen in the string, so I need something that only extract comma and hyphen if followed by a number.

**And to clearify, the dots and hyphens may or may not exist, sometimes not the html either**

Comment: Use DOM methods (e.g el.innerHTML) to parse HTML not a RegEx

Comment: Its a javascript function, and all the html may not exist, sometimes its just the number

Comment: Are you trying to access it within an HTML doc with access to the DOM, or is this strictly a string within JS?

Comment: Better add some more examples then, is there always a trailing %?

Comment: `/-?[\d|,?|.?]*/.exec('-18.9%')`

Comment: Please do not be using regex to parse HTML. There are countless other questions that are asking this, please do a proper search on this site.

Comment: It is a javascript function within datatables, summarizing columns in the footer, and sometimes the cells contains this html.

Comment: var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

Comment: I am almost there, I just need that the dot and hyphen needs to be followed by a digit/number to match

Comment: So what if your HTML happens to have a number in an attribute? example: `<div style="width: 25%">18.6%</div>`? => Don't parse HTML with regex. Sooner or later it will break

Answer (score 2):

[Don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839). Instead use a [DOM parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), which makes it a piece of cake:

```js
var str = '<div style="color: red; display.: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> -18.9%</div>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
// get text content and remove '%' from it.
console.log(doc.documentElement.textContent.replace(/%/, ''));
```

Note that this also works if `str` is just plain text, like `25.3`.

If it represents a valid number you can convert it with `parseFloat` or the unitary `+`. Note that thousands separator(s) will need to be removed first with a `replace`.

If your actual HTML string is more complex and has other text nodes in it, then use the usual DOM methods to find the node of your interest, for instance:

```
doc.querySelector('div').textContent
```

Comment: Why won't your solution work for him? It is the most precise I think.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're dealing with a string, that appears to be taken from HTML. If this is the case, and you can't get the `innerHTML` property there are 2 options.

**1. Convert to HTML and use innerText**

```
var tempEl = document.createElement('div');
tempEl.innerHTML = '<div style="color: red; display.: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> -18.9%</div>';

var myNumber = parseFloat(tempEl.children[0].innerText.trim())
```

will result in the number

```
-18.9
```

**2. Regex**
This regex will match a string starting with a `-` and followed by a whole or decimal number

```
/(-)?\d+(\.\d*)*/g
```

Using your example:

```
<div style="color: red; display.: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> -18.9%</div>
```

will result in a match of

```
-18.9
```

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VIvJlp/2).

Comment: Your regex almost works, but the hyphens may or may not exists

Comment: Another question, sometimes the number will look like this: 19,079.50 will the comma be replaced with space or merged? Its the only thing that doesnt work right now.

Comment: Could the whole regex above be inverted? to match everything but that. that way I can use replace method.

Comment: I fixed it: [^\-*(\d+(\.\d*)?)]

Comment: No I did not... [^\-(\d+(\.\d)?)] matches dots and hyphen elsewhere in the string

Comment: Maybe you could provide more detail into what you're doing, it seems over-complicated. You want to replace the number within the tags? I would use  option #1 or something like what @trincot recommended and use `innerText` to replace the number within the tag.

Comment: Tronik, sooner or later your regex solution will break. Don't use regex on HTML. Developers commonly agree on that (out of experience). Think of what would happen if there are digits somewhere in the HTML tags (in their attributes). Do yourself a favour and [follow the advise of experienced developers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839)

Answer (score -1):

here's the simple regular expression for it
`[-0-9]+.?[0-9]`

Comment: Doesn't work if the number contains more than one decimal

Comment: it works for this value `-134343.4545454549%`. Perhaps can you give me an example of your sample cases.